# regular expression to delete the 0 after dash sign

Tags: python, regex

I have a pandas dataframe column of numbers which all have a dash in between, for example :

> "123-045"

I am wondering is there anyway to delete the zero after the dash sign, to make the above example to

> "123-45"

? And is it possible to apply the process condition to the entire column??

I have used a for loop to check each digit after the dash sign, using the python string function. But the number of rows is large, and the for loop takes forever.

Comment: You could split your string by the regex `/\-0/` then join it again with a `-`; Check the `re` package for split and then you can use `str.join`

Comment: Combining the two answers below you could first import `from re import sub` and then simply do `sub('(?<=-)0+', '', string)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Series.str.replace` method with regex `(?<=-)0+` to remove `0` after `-`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ["123-045"]})

df
#         a
#0  123-045

df.a.str.replace('(?<=-)0+', '')
#0    123-45
#Name: a, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If `str` is your string then it could be as simple as this:

```
str = re.sub("-.", "-", str)
```

Or with pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': ["assa-dssd-sd"]})
print (df.key.str.replace("-.", "-"))
```